# TYPO3-NEOS How to disable ajax on admin editor

Tags: typo3, aloha-editor, neoscms

i'm new with typo3 neos and it's editor (aloha)

I want to make this editor as an admin panel too, so it needs to load every javascript/css included within the page, the problem is, the editor load page using ajax, so the javascript is not loaded, how can i disable ajax on the editor?
at least it can disable get request so whenever the url changes, the page get reloaded.
Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by admin panel? I can try to answer the question, but currently the editor is pretty tigtly coupled to the editing view. So if you want to load it in your own Backend module you probably have to load an unmodified version of it.

Comment: i mean, page for admin to create/edit/view backend item (e.g photos, content, etc).
is it a bad implementation?